# Anyway to change color without using windows.h

Tags: c++

I wanna change the colour/color of my program text. I don't wanna do it on windows.h as I want my program to run on other platforms. I also don't wanna do `system("color 0a");` is there any ways that i can fix that? if so please help.

Comment: Ncurses is a cross-platform terminal abstraction library that can do colors among other things.

Comment: ncurses does not exist in Windows

Comment: [pdcurses](https://pdcurses.sourceforge.io/) begs to differ.

Comment: @ MichaelChourdakis [Sure it does](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/ncurses.htm) - and other implementations exist as well.

Comment: This might be a good opportunity to learn how to abstract platform specific behavior behind a common interface.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to change color through `#include <conio.h>`, but as I can see you want it to be cross-platform and `conio.h` is pure DOS based, that's probably not what you want.
So with that considered I would recommend using **ncurses**. It's really flexible and usefull library capable of infinite terminal styling. It has even a Windows alternative **pdcurses** that has identical syntax.

See more at [pdcurses](https://pdcurses.sourceforge.io/) or [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).